# Insert data into azure table failed

Tags: java, android, azure, insert

I am trying to develop a simple application for android using azure mobile services and database, I have used the following code snippets but can't seem to insert any data into my azure table.
The following is the code I used to add the data:

```
public void createTable(String name, String userBirthday, String email)
{
    userInformationTable = mClient.getTable(UserInformation.class);

    item = new UserInformation();
    item.mId = "1";
    item.mEmail = email;
    item.mUserBirthday = userBirthday;
    item.mName = name;

    mClient.getTable(UserInformation.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<UserInformation>()
    {
        public void onCompleted(UserInformation entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
        {
            if (exception == null) {
                // Insert succeeded
                Log.e("Succeed", "Insert Succeeded");
            } else {
                // Insert failed
                Log.e("Nope", "Insert Failed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The UserInformation Class is as below:

```
public class UserInformation {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
public String mId;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("name")
public String mName;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("email")
public String mEmail;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("user_birthday")
public String mUserBirthday;

public UserInformation(){

}
public UserInformation(String Id, String name, String email, String userBirthday)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Can you print stack trace for the exception and supply the error information for helping solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many different error roots for that.

Improve your log using this code, this will give you further information about the error nature.

```
public void createTable(String name, String userBirthday, String email)
{
    userInformationTable = mClient.getTable(UserInformation.class);

    if(userInformationTable == null)
    {
       // Insert succeeded
       Log.e("Table problem", "There's no table");
    }
    else
    {
        item = new UserInformation();
        item.mId = "1";
        item.mEmail = email;
        item.mUserBirthday = userBirthday;
        item.mName = name;

        userInformationTable.insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<UserInformation>()
            {
                public void onCompleted(UserInformation entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
                {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        // Insert succeeded
                        Log.e("Succeed", "Insert Succeeded");
                    } else {
                        // Insert failed
                        Log.e("Error Message", exception.getMessage());
                        Log.e("Error Full", exception.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}}
```

Most probably a connection issue or less probably there aren't tables with that name.